# How to swap the column value and How to Concat using MYSQL

Tags: mysql

1. How to swap the same columns value ?

**table_name**

```
id    value

1      0

2      1

3      0

4      1
```

How to Change the values 0 to 1 and 1 to 0 using mysql query?

1. How to print the following o/p ?

table_name

```
id name

1   x

2   y

3   NULL
```

If the name contains value it should print as "Hi X" else if the name is NULL it should print as "Hello Guest".

My O/P should be like below

```
name

Hi X

Hi y

Hello Guest
```

How can this be done ?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)**

You can simply do:

```
SELECT id, NOT value AS value
FROM tbl
```

`NOT` will switch `0` to `1` and vice versa.

---

**2)**

You can use `COALESCE()` in conjunction with `CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(CONCAT('Hi ', name), 'Hello Guest') AS name
FROM tbl
```

--

- If at least one item in `CONCAT()` is `NULL`, then `CONCAT()` will return `NULL` regardless of any other item in its parameters.
- `COALESCE()` outputs the first non-`NULL` parameter.

--

So if `name` is `NULL`, then `CONCAT()` will return `NULL`, and `COALESCE()` will output `Hello Guest` instead.